# When accessing a react web app, the whole react library is transferred to my browser in that first request?

Tags: reactjs, architecture

I know that react is a library that works on the frontend, but the first time accessing a react website will transfer the whole library? Does not that consume a whole lot of bandwidth?

Comment: Yes, it does, which is why there are various packaging tweaks to reduce the app download.

Comment: Thank you so much! @DaveNewton